# Resolution Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

I started writing a Google TV app and DisplayMetrics.widthPixels = 1804 and heightPixels = 1008 and densityDpi is set to 320.

Has anyone a setup for the graphical layout editor, because I can't use it for WYSIWYG. I allways have to start it on the real Google TV device (Logitech Revue). Depends it on my TV or is this setup up for every Google TV Device?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I started writing a Google TV app and DisplayMetrics.widthPixels = 1804 and heightPixels = 1008 and densityDpi is set to 320.

That sounds like a 1080p screen with overscan.

> Has anyone a setup for the graphical layout editor, because I can't use it for WYSIWYG.

Use 1080p and follow the [Google TV design guidelines](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_patterns#Display) for dealing with overscan.

> Depends it on my TV or is this setup up for every Google TV Device?

The amount of overscan varies by device.

Comment: @mars3142: Yeah, overscan is the price you pay for building a new technology (Google TV) on the charred embers of an ancient technology (TV, which has been around for nearly a century)... :-)